# json manipulation and comprison typescripts (test equal)

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, testing, city

and thanks for the support.

i am haveing prbolem to compare two obj of City, one created and one read and hopefully "converted" from a json file.

The one imported:

```
import * as citiesJson from '../resources/cities.json';
const cities_test: City[] = citiesJson as City[];
```

The one created:

```
const milan: City = { name: 'Milan', population: 1371498 };
    const napels: City = { name: 'Napels', population: 911000 };
    const rome: City = { name: 'Rome', population: 2758334 };
    const resultSort: City[] = [milan, napels, rome];
```

the test result `expect(getSortedItems(cities_imported)).toEqual(city_created);` failed and the console.log of them both is:

Imported

```
console.log                                                                                                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  '0': [Getter],
  '1': [Getter],
  '2': [Getter],
  default: [
    { name: 'Milan', population: 1371498 },
    { name: 'Naples', population: 911000 },
    { name: 'Rome', population: 2758334 }
  ]
}

     at Object.<anonymous> (dao/sortAlg.test.ts:30:17)
```

Created

```
console.log                                                                                                                                                                                            
   [
     { name: 'Milan', population: 1371498 },
     { name: 'Napels', population: 911000 },
     { name: 'Rome', population: 2758334 }
   ]

     at Object.<anonymous> (dao/sortAlg.test.ts:31:17)
```

i am doing something wrong but is not clear where. the first idea is about the printing of the imported json file and this part:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  '0': [Getter],
  '1': [Getter],
  '2': [Getter],
  default:
```

is there a way to manipulate json file in order to make the comparison succesfull?

Comment: You don't need `* as` when importing JSON.